# Data Access Layer with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I created a default asp.net MVC Project in Visual Studio 2015  to get all the Authentication Goodness by default. Now I try  to create an 3 Layer architecture with an DataAccess Layer and would use the same DB for the authentication as for the other data. I would usually put the DbContext in the DataAccess Layer. But since OWIN needs in on startup this doesn't really work, since I would have to access the Data Access Layer from the view layer.

Is there some best practice how to structure the project with OWIN authentication enabled? Or should I just make one project who contains everything (which sounds ab it messy) or use an other db for the data than for the authentication?

Comment: If the purpose of using a N-tier solution is to seperate the db access to a own layer then I suggest you to also add the db calls which is made by the authentication to that layer. Or else you will have db calls in both the GUI project and the data access layer.

Comment: The problem is, that owin needs an application context to work on startup. Or what is the best practice when you work with owin?

Comment: Most likely is your current app build so it wont work without db context in startup. But it's perfectly fine to use owin without adding a application context to the app builder.

Comment: Aaah, I completely tot that erong.. didn't notice that this is just dependency injection. Replaced it with AutoFac and it works nicely.

Comment: I could not inject the dependency injection, please give me a demo example/code.

Comment: From your comment,  I do not really now what exactly you are trying and how your setup looks like. I suggest you make a new thread and describe your project, code and problem a bit. If you just try to use autofac with MVC there are several tutorials like https://www.codeproject.com/articles/808894/ioc-in-asp-net-mvc-using-autofac

Comment: @NPadrutt I have asked a question, could you kindly check and suggest me a solution. the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541696/how-to-access-owin-request-variables-outside-of-apicontroller-in-mvc5-restful-ap